# Magento 2 Unknown file automatically created on root folder

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Here I have 2 issues.

1. Some random malware files are keep generating after a couple of days.
2. index.php file altered after some time and add header code by which our all SEO texts goes into japanes.

Files which generates on root directory :

[image]

Index File altered code:

[image]

Comment: Well that sucks, but what is your question?

Comment: I want to track malware code and want to implement some logic to prevent it so it won't happen again.

Comment: Use the Magento security scanning tool to identify any known malware present https://magento.com/security